# why the armature its faded in the outliner?

Tags: objects

why the armature its faded in the outliner? what does that mean, i cannot edit it,even bones dont appear, its like blocked or something?.i tried to parent (ctrl+p) back again and the popup doesnt come out

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the *Object Properties* Panel and make sure you have **Selectable** checked in the *Visibility* section.

[image: Visibility]

In 2.81, the faded text indicates that **Show in Viewport** is unchecked.

Comment: thanks yeah this happened in 2.81...

Comment: A useful hint is that where these used to be visible in the outliner, they are now hidden by default, click the filter button above for outliner settings.